# X11 image to template matching in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, x11

I am working on a project of a bot for a game. The idea is to get a real-time screenshot of the game window (using X11, I work on Linux) and convert it to a cv::Mat. This is how I do it:

```
void WindowCapture::getImage(std::vector<uint8_t>& pixels, int &width, int &height, int &bitsPerPixel) {
    XWindowAttributes attributes{};
    XGetWindowAttributes(display, window, &attributes);

    width = attributes.width;
    height = attributes.height;

    XImage* img = XGetImage(display, window, 0, 0, width, height, AllPlanes, ZPixmap);
    bitsPerPixel = img->bits_per_pixel;

    pixels.resize(width * height * 4);

    std::memcpy(&pixels[0], img->data, pixels.size());

    XDestroyImage(img);
}

...

int width, height, bitsPerPixel;
std::vector<uint8_t> pixels;
windowCapture->getImage(pixels, width, height, bitsPerPixel);
cv::Mat gameImage{height, width, bitsPerPixel > 24 ? CV_8UC4 : CV_8UC3, &pixels[0]};
```

Now, I have another image, a screenshot of the game object I want to detect, saved as a .png and loaded using [cv::imread(...)](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56). I want to do a template match similar to the one shown in the OpenCV [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/de/da9/tutorial_template_matching.html) with both images, but I get this error:

```
error: (-215:Assertion failed) (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) && type == _templ.type() && _img.dims() <= 2 in function 'matchTemplate'
```

The error is because the real-time image have type CV_8UC4 and the object scrrenshot have type CV_8UC3. I don't if this error is for how I get the image from X11 or the way I load the scrrenshot from file. I tried to change the real-time image type to CV_8UC3 using [cv::Mat::converTo(...)](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#adf88c60c5b4980e05bb556080916978b) but not work. How I could solve this? thanks!

Comment: check type/depth/channel count of everything. then use cvtColor to take care of channels and convertTo for the type (if either of those is the issue). convertTo does not change number of channels! it only changes element type.

Comment: You're right! the problem was the channels, and using cvtColor solved the problem. Thank you!